# Changing Arrays in Javascript from Input Tags

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a 2D array that looks something like this:

```
var header = [A, B, C]
var allData = [
                [A1, B1, C1]
                [A2, B2, C2]
                [A3, B3, C3]
              ];
```

Save for the array is much, much larger and has many empty indexes.

I have used AngularJS to create a spreadsheet of sorts. It is formed with input text boxes, where the values of the boxes are what is in the arrays.

```
<script>
    sheet= function($scope, $parse){
    $scope.columns = header;
    $scope.rows = allData.length;
    $scope.cells = {};
    $scope.values = allData.map(function(c,row){
        return c.map(function(data, ind){
            return {
                content: data,
                model: null,
            };
        });
    });
    };
</script>

<div ng-app ng-controller="sheet">
    <center><table>
        <tr class="column-label">
            <td ng-repeat="column in columns">{{column}}</td>
        <tr ng-repeat="value in values">
            <td class="row-label" ng-repeat="data in value">
                <div>
                    <input type="text" ng-model="data.content" value="{{data.content}}">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table></center>
</div>
```

However, since many of these array index will be empty, the user will have to fill them in. I want to figure out how to dynamically change the allData array as the user types his data in--or perhaps not dynamically, but in a way that he could click a button and it updates the array prior to sending the information off to the server.

For example, if the user changes "C2" to "2C", I want the allData array to be updated as so:

```
var allData = [
                [A1, B1, C1]
                [A2, B2, 2C]
                [A3, B3, C3]
              ];
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Isn't angularjs doing it got you? And also, do you really need `value="{{data.content}}"` since you already have `ng-model` present?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working with a 2 dimensional array. You'll need to keep indexes to the cells that have content so you can update and read them. The cells in the display version (the inputs) will need to have corresponding identifiers, probably IDs. You only need members in the arrays for cells that have content.

So write some generic read and write functions that set and get values based on the index, e.g.

```
var base = [];

function setValue(rowIdx, colIdx, value) {
  var col; 
  var row = base[rowIdx];

  if (typeof row == 'undefined') {
    row = base[rowIdx] = [];
  }
  col = row[colIdx];

  if (typeof col == 'undefined') {
    col = row[colIdx] = [];
  }
  col[colIdx] = value;
}

function getValue(rowIdx, colIdx) {
  var col; 
  var row = base[rowIdx];

  if (typeof row == 'undefined') {
    return row;
  }
  col = row[colIdx];

  if (typeof col == 'undefined') {
    return col;
  }
  return col[colIdx];
}
```

Now put a listener on a parent of the input elements (you may want to put them in a table to keep them neat) and when you get a change event, see where it came from and update the array if required. It doesn't take much more effort to put a function or formula in a cell for a computed value.

You then need a function to update the display from the *base* Array, so changes made in one place flow to other calculated cells. You can even make each cell member an object that has not only the value, but a formula to calculate the value, so you can hold the updated value and the formula that generated it. And you can further add references to the cells that have a formula involving a particular cell, so that updating the cell means just updating the related formula cells.

And so on… You'll need to add the functions that communicate with the view.

The above is just an example, you should probably create a single object to hold all the methods and data, probably using the module pattern, but a prototype approach will work too.